# PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND does not end a specific session

Tags: session, amazon-redshift

I was unable to drop a redshift db because of a connection:

```
Couldn't drop my_db : #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "my_db" is being accessed by other users
```

I connected (via psql) to another db of the same cluster, and checked to see the pid of of my pending session:

```
my_other_db=# select procpid from pg_stat_activity where datname='my_db';
  procpid 
 ---------
    20457
(1 row)
```

So I attempted a call to PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND:

```
my_other_db=# select pg_terminate_backend(20457);
 pg_terminate_backend
----------------------
                    1
(1 row)
```

But when I checked my pg_stat_activity, my blocking session was still here:

```
my_other_db=# select procpid from pg_stat_activity where datname='my_db';
  procpid 
 ---------
    20457
(1 row)
```

And I was still unable to drop my db.

Any idea ? (I had to restart the cluster to get rid of it, which is not a satisfying solution)

(Of course, I tried with another session, which I managed to terminate)

Answer (score 0):

When you cancel the query or terminate the session Redshift has to return the database to a safe state by reverting any changes already made. This can take a varying amount of time depending on what the session was doing and any other queries are inflight that affect the same table(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following

1. select pg_terminate_backend([pid])
2. cancel [pid]
3. Kill the query via the Redshift console

On rare occasions, ghost pids will continue to run. In these instances, you can reboot the cluster.